Sending non-Salesforce browser notifications
Is it feasible to send non-native Salesforce browser notifications to users ? This would be the same type of notification as a native Salesforce notification (Account / Case assignment etc) but it would be in their browser outside of Salesforce. We users using Chrome with multiple tabs open and other apps. We would like for the notifications to pop up on their screen no matter what tab they have open.
Is there a go-to way to do this ? I was wondering if Omni-Channel might be a solution but it looks like the user needs to be in the same tab for that. I'm guessing any solution would be in the realm of LWC.
Thank you for any help.

If you're typing something in your active tab, do you really want an app in a different tab suddenly popping up a notification window in your active and hijacking your keyboard input?

Apparently that is the wish by the users, yes.
